# How to use dumpdata/loaddata in Django with self-referential tables?

Tags: django, postgresql, self-referencing-table

I have a Django 1.7 app, developed against sqlite3, and moving to Postgresql.  One model table called Place has a parent relation to itself.  I used dumpdata to create a .json extract.

When I attempt to use loaddata to read the extract into the Postgres db, Django (not postgres) gives me:

`django.core.serializers.base.DeserializationError: Problem installing fixture '/home/ugliest/project/thub/dbdump25jan_nat.json': Place matching query does not exist;`

This tells me that django is validating the data before loading it into the database.  Is there a way to allow this data in before validation?  I know that Postgres has the ability to defer constraint checking, but even if I could trigger that from django, it wouldn't prevent django from validating.  How to get the data in?

I feel like I'm missing something obvious.  This seems like it would happen often, and have a known simple fix.  Do I *really* have to write some custom mess to reorder the extract file?

Edit: FWIW, never found an answer, and wrote a custom mess to reorder things.

Comment: Did you find to answer for it? I am stuck with the same issue.